# In C++, how can I use a nested class type in an other nested class (the two nested classes are under the same outer class)

Tags: c++, class, oop, inner-classes

I have a class `List` which has two nested classes: `ListItem` and `ListIterator`. In the `ListIterator` class I have an attribute of the type `ListItem`. In the header file "List.h" I defined the `ListItem` as a private attribute of the class `ListIterator` and it compiled perfectly.
But, in the "List.cpp" file, when I try to define the constructor of `ListIterator` it gives me the error:

```
List.cpp: In constructor ‘List::ListIterator::ListIterator(bool)’:
List.cpp:24:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘List::ListItem::ListItem()’
List::ListIterator::ListIterator(bool reverse){
                                             ^
List.cpp:24:46: note: candidates are:
List.cpp:7:1: note: List::ListItem::ListItem(void*)
List::ListItem::ListItem(void* data){
^
List.cpp:7:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from List.cpp:1:0:
List.h:2:8: note: List::ListItem::ListItem(const List::ListItem&)
class ListItem {
      ^
List.h:2:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Here is my List.h file:

```
class List{
class ListItem {
    public:
        ListItem(void*);
        void* getData();
        ListItem* getNext();
        ListItem* getPrev();
    private:
        void* data;
        ListItem* next;
        ListItem* prev;
};

class ListIterator {
    public:
        ListIterator(bool);
        bool hasNext();
        void* next();
    private:
        bool reverse;
        ListItem current;
};
public:

    List();
    ~List();
    long getSize();
    int addData(void*);
    void* remove(long);
    long indexOf(void*);
    ListIterator* cellAt(long);
    ListIterator& iterator(bool);
private:
    long size;
    ListItem head;
    ListItem tail;
};
```

And here is my List.cpp file:

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* ListItem */
List::ListItem::ListItem(void* data){
    this->data = data;
}

void* List::ListItem::getData(){
    return this->data;
}

List::ListItem* List::ListItem::getNext(){
    return this->next;
}

List::ListItem* List::ListItem::getPrev(){
    return this->prev;
}

/* ListIterator */
List::ListIterator::ListIterator(bool reverse){
    this->reverse = reverse;
}

bool List::ListIterator::hasNext(){
    return false;
}

void* List::ListIterator::next(){
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not about class nesting but about members initialization.

When building a `ListIterator` you are also building its members, so a `ListItem`, then you need to specify a ctor call for it as it has one user-defined:

```
List::ListIterator::ListIterator(bool b) : current(something) {
    ...
}
```

This is the way to express how `current` is initialized.

Comment: And I replace something with something like current(ListItem l)?

Comment: You need to pass a value, to solve the problem think like "what my listiterator object should own at the beginning?". I suspect that your listiterator should point to some listitem, right? Then pass a listitem (probably a pointer to)... Read about iterators implementation examples.